# Sails.js multiple controllers/models to one view

Tags: sails.js

I've been trying out sails and so far I've been able to display an index of all items in a database table model. However, I have two different models, modelA and modelB and I would like to display them to a single view called dashboard in the root of views - /dashboard.

However, I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to get the different controllers display the list unto the dashboard. How do I get this done, can it be done with the two different controllers and if so how. Or can I create a separate controller called dashboard calling the different instances of the models?

Having a hard time wrapping my head around this ...

Comment: You would have a controller with a dashboard function (or w/e) and that controller would render a view and pass to it the data you need. OR, you render the view with some controller and inside the view you fetch the data with a request (you would be fetching from a controller action that returns just data and not a view)

Comment: Is there a way I can make my controller point to my view in a different directory? res.vew points to /views/mycontroller/dashboard while I have dashboard on root of /views/dashboard.

Comment: Yes, res.view takes as a param the path to the view. You can put whatever you want. In addition, you can configurate a route in routes.js and specify the view there. http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-view

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want a controller that fetches data from 2 different models and sends that data into a view.

Since node now supports it, i would use async/await for the example, but its the same with callbacks but you have to nest your calls or use caolan async.

```
const DashBoardController = {
  async show(req, res){
    const instanceA = await ModelA.findOne(1) // I used a hardcoded number for simplicity
    const instanceB = await ModelB.findOne(1)
    res.view('mycrontroller/dashboard', {instanceA, instanceB})
  }
}

export DashBoardController;
```

Then in your view you just access it with the name of the keys you defined...`instanceA` and `instanceB`

If that's not what you meant, then let me know.